# How to use Different Java versions eclipse in Linux mint?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, linux-mint

I have many Java versions installed on my laptop.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for naruto: 
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java              1091      manual mode
```

I had installed openjdk8 as `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

oracle jdk8 by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and oracle jdk9 by

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

I want to create new Java program which usages Oracle Java 8 or 9
(whenever  I select Java 9 by `sudo update-alternatives --config java` Eclipse doesn't lunch. I don't why that is happening) but Eclipse uses openjdk8.

[image]

So **How can I create new Project with Oracle Java 8 in Eclipse** (or 9 if possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may even set a different Java version for each project:

Open project's properties:

- Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > JRE System Library (I recommend to chose always an "execution evironment").
- Java Compiler > Check "Enable project settings", uncheck "Use compliance from execution environment..." and chose your preferred value from the dropdown.
- Project facets > Java: Set the same value from the dropdown.

Always keep these three parameters set to *the same Java version* on each project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window > Preferences > java > Installed JREs and Add JRE you like

Source :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O82qvBtgkg4

Comment: Click Search and let it look in /usr/lib/jvm/